# generar un txt con cabecera y detalle en php

Tags: php

Quiero generar reportes en txt PHP.

Pero no obtengo el resultado deseado. Necesito que me muestre solo el encabezado una sola vez. Y me lo repite.

Tengo una tabla con el encabezado y otra con el detalle.

Este es mi código:

```
$sqlPol = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM polizasap_enc a
                                    RIGHT join polizasap_det b
                                    on a.id_Rec = b.id_Rec");
        $file = 'datos.txt';
        $jump = "\r\n";
        $separator = "  ";

        $fp = fopen($file , 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");;

        foreach ($sqlPol as $key => $row) {

            $registroCab = $agrupador.$separator.$sociedad.$separator.$ejercicio.$separator 
                          .$claseDocumento.$separator.$fechaDoc.$separator.$fechaDoc.$separator 
                          .$referencia.$separator.$texto.$separator.$claveContabilizacion
                          .$separator.$ctaContable.$separator.$importe.$separator.$separator 
                          .$asignacion.$separator.$asignacion.$separator.$separator
                          .$separator.$moneda.$jump;

            $registroDet = $agrupador.$separator.$separator.$separator.$separator.$separator 
                           .$separator.$separator.$separator.$claveContabilizacion 
                           .$separator.$ctaContable.$separator.$importe.$separator 
                           .$separator.$asignacion.$separator.$asignacion.$separator
                           .$separator.$separator.$moneda.$jump;

             fwrite($fp, $registroCab.$registroDet);
        }
        fclose($fp);
```

Lo que obtengo actualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna sugerencia de como podría esto que necesito. Gracias por su apoyo

Comment: Hasta ahora entendí el problema, aclara, por favor si por cada registro se muestran siempre dos líneas o pueden ser más y cuáles son las variables que tienen en común. Voy a borrar la respuesta para tratar de replantear.

Comment: Pueden ser N numero de lineas por cada registro, el agrupador es el que cambiaria, primer registro 1, segundo registro 2, etc.. esa sería las variables en común

Comment: Necesitas algún dato extra o lo comentado anteriormente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas identificar en qué momento incluir registro con encabezados y cuando solo los detalles. Se puede hacer fácilmente creando una variable donde vayas actualizando el agrupador, en los comentarios del código te lo explico:

```
    $sqlPol = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM polizasap_enc a
                                RIGHT join polizasap_det b
                                on a.id_Rec = b.id_Rec");
    $file = 'datos.txt';
    $jump = "\r\n";
    $separator = "  ";

    $fp = fopen($file , 'w') or die("Unable to open file!");

    // Definir variable para saber cuándo mostrar encabezados
    $grupoAnterior = '';
    foreach ($sqlPol as $key => $row) {
        // El agrupador es diferente al anterior que se mostró?
        if($agrupador != $grupoAnterior) {
            // Crear registro con encabezados y detalles
            $registroDet = $agrupador.$separator.$sociedad.$separator.$ejercicio.$separator 
                      .$claseDocumento.$separator.$fechaDoc.$separator.$fechaDoc.$separator 
                      .$referencia.$separator.$texto.$separator.$claveContabilizacion
                      .$separator.$ctaContable.$separator.$importe.$separator.$separator 
                      .$asignacion.$separator.$asignacion.$separator.$separator
                      .$separator.$moneda.$jump;
            // Actualizar variable
            $grupoAnterior = $agrupador;
        } else {
            // Crear registro sin encabezados
            $registroDet = $agrupador.$separator.$separator.$separator.$separator.$separator 
                       .$separator.$separator.$separator.$claveContabilizacion 
                       .$separator.$ctaContable.$separator.$importe.$separator 
                       .$separator.$asignacion.$separator.$asignacion.$separator
                       .$separator.$separator.$moneda.$jump;
        }
        // Se guarda solo una variable
        fwrite($fp, $registroDet);
    }
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Entonces usaría 2 foreach? uno para el encabezado y otro para el detalle? todas las variables vienen de la consulta, el encabezado cambia cada 2 líneas

Comment: @PedroIslasReséndiz, listo, con esto debe funcionar

Comment: Excelente, es lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias!!!!!